# community / cluster detection algorithm in networks - implemented in javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, social-networking, cluster-analysis

I am looking for an implementation of a community detection algorithm in javascript. Louvain algorithm, or any other would do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a recent implementation of [Louvain community detection](https://sites.google.com/site/findcommunities/) in JavaScript, in a way it is easy to use it with D3.js:

- https://github.com/upphiminn/jLouvain

As a side note, as I was not aware of it, I wrote a greedy modularity maximization for my project [TagOverflow](http://stared.github.io/tagoverflow/) (see also [some description](https://github.com/stared/tagoverflow#methods-and-tricks)). It works good enough (see example below), but this `jLouvain` is both a better algorithm and with a better implementation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this [one](http://harthur.github.com/clusterfck/)?

clusterfck is a JavaScript library for hierarchical clustering. Clustering is used to group similar items together. Hierarchical clustering in particular is used when a hierarchy of items is needed or when the number of clusters isn't known ahead of time

Comment: The tool you propose seems to be designed for natural clustering, not graph clustering (community detection). In order to apply it, seinecle should first process a distance matrix, reflecting node-to-node distances. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946993/any-good-javascript-graph-library